# CV No Longer Works

Tags: upgrade, cv

I am trying to use the CV command line tool and it is no longer working. I think it sopped working when I upgraded to 5.68.0. I am also running Drupal 9.5.11 on Amazon Linux 2. I have PHP 8 running.

The error is In Drupal8.php line 414: Class "ComposerAutoloaderInitDrupal8" not found.

Looking at the line Drupal8.php you can see it attempt to call the class. On [line 416](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/7b5c6cc71cf88fbc8ae9de87ae034f239cf86216/CRM/Utils/System/Drupal8.php#L416C4-L416C99) of the same file there is a comment that says

```
// @Todo: do we need to handle case where $_SERVER has no HTTP_HOST key, ie. when run via cli?
```

Should it be expected that cv does not work any longer?  Does anyone know the cutoff for when cv stopped working with CiviCRM if that is the case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What version of `cv` are you running?  You may need to upgrade.
The current version (from `cv -V`) is `v0.3.48`

You can download the latest from https://github.com/civicrm/cv

Comment: I am running v0.3.48. Sorry I did not include the version in the question.